# Codeigniter mod_rewrite for both root and subdirectory

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have:

`root/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

it works perfectly send all request(except file and folder) to index.php. I need it to work to my subfolder too.

I have .htaccess in subfolder `root/demos/project` contain:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

but doesn't work.

I try this in root/.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^demos/project/(.*)$ demos/project/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Doesn't work.

this:

```
RewriteRule ^demos/project/(.*)$ demos/project/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

get Internal Server Error 'missconfiguration'

and many several way, but everything I tried, I just get these: 501(default from server) and 404(from ci in root);

I use codeigniter in both `root` and `demos/project` and just want to 'hide' index.php from both, how to do this correctly ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/project/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

does that work?

You could also just place another .htaccess in your demo/project folder.

EDIT:

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/project/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

EDIT2:

If you get a 404 not found page just change your config.php in root/application/config/config.php from the following:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

to:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Comment: Internal Server Error `missconfiguration`. :(

Comment: Still same: `500 internal server error`. I added .htaccess to my subfolder too with similiar sintax, everything I tried, I only get these: 500 or 404.

Comment: when you get 404 it should work. Have you deleted index page in your config file? root/application/config/config.php: `$config['index_page'] = "";`

Comment: But did you get a 404 page? then my second edit should work. if you get a 500 error it does not work anyway.